# TFS and SVN code Merge

Tags: svn, version-control, tfs, version

We are a small team of 8. 3 are from other country and they are using the Source controller as TFS and TFS server is also located there and they have only 4 licence. So we (5 developers) are using SVN source controller as local source controller and for every 3 days we are taking the TFS latest and merging the changes from and to SVN & TFS. Really this is overkilling and hour consuming task. They don't want to change the TFS ( Not event add ins ). So what i can use to merge the code between two source controllers. Is it i can use SVN-Bridge to Merge the code without changing or modifying the TFS Server. Please guide me on this. (Worst case they might go for add ins, for sure no other source controllers than Microsoft Product).

hhhmmmmmm, i'm sitting in front of monitor and hitting the F5 on this page, Please save my hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that [SvnBridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge) indeed may be able to help you. By using SvnBridge you'll be able to use a single backend for the code, whilst using Subversion to talk to it. I'm not sure if you need TFS licenses for the users on SvnBridge though.

Branching works pretty much the same way in TFS and Svn, although the speed indicates that it's not a cheap copy on the TFS backend, like it is usually in Subversion.

Tagging works totally different in TFS, you'd have to check the SvnBridge documentation if there's a way to interop here. If there isn't you can always use branches to tag stuff, like you normally do in Subversion.

SvnBridge doesn't need to be run on the TFS server; the first beta they shipped (before it was available on Codeplex) actually *required* you to run it locally, and connect to localhost:[some port]